# Angular 2 - SystemJS - Change Default extension

Tags: angular, caching, systemjs

I'm trying to change the default extension of all the files of my Angular 2 App with no success.

Bellow you can find the configuration of the systemjs.config.js:

```html
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',

            'powerbi-client': 'npm:powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: '/app/main',
                defaultExtension: 'js?v=3.1'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js?v=3.1'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

The app it's loaded with the following code:

```html
System.import('/app/main').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
```

Analysing the network activity it's possible to see that the default extension for the app it's .js instead of .js?v=3.1

[image]

Am I doing some error in the systemjs.config.js configuration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer by own :)
Bellow you can find the fix in the systemjs.config.js:

```js
/// <reference path="node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js" />
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',

            'powerbi-client': 'npm:powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: '/app/main',
                defaultExtension: 'js?v=3.1'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js?v=3.1'
            },
            '/app': { defaultExtension: 'js?v=3.1' }

        }
    });
})(this);
```